# How can I calculate the Eisenstein series of a complex lattice?

Tags: elliptic-curves, integer-lattices

Suppose I have a lattice $\Lambda = \mathbb{Z}+\frac{3}{2}i\mathbb{Z}$. How would I go about calculating $G_{2n}(\Lambda)$ for a given $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Does the Wikipedia article [Eisenstein series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_series) have the information you need?

Answer (score 1):

Up to the $\zeta(4),\zeta(6)$ constants this is $E_4,E_6$, some modular forms with rational coefficients.

$E_6(i)=0$ and $E_4(i)$ is given in term of the beta function $\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3+x}}$, then
$E_{2k}(z)\in \Bbb{Z}[E_4(z),E_6(z),\Delta(z)]$ so $E_{2k}(i\frac32)\in \Bbb{Z}[\frac16,E_4(i\frac32),E_6(i\frac32)]$

and $E_4(i\frac32),E_6(i\frac32)$ are algebraic over $\Bbb{Z}[E_6(i)]$, this is because the coefficients of $$\prod_{\gamma \in \Gamma_0(6)\backslash SL_2(\Bbb{Z})} (X-E_6(\frac32 \gamma(z)))$$ are modular forms $\in M_{(d-n)6}(SL_2(\Bbb{Z}))$ with rational coefficients, so they are in $\Bbb{Q}[E_4(z),E_6(z)]$.

Comment: I don't really follow. Given that $G_{2k}(\frac{3}{2}i) = \frac{1}{6}m + G_6(\frac{3}{2}i)n$ with $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$, how do I actually go about finding $m$ and $n$? Note, I'm asking this question in relation to elliptic curves; I don't know anything about modular curves.

Comment: $G_{2k}(z) = \sum_{4a+6b=2k} c_{a,b} G_4(z)^aG_6(z)^b$ for some $c_{a,b}\in \Bbb{Q}$ that you find by looking at the first few coefficients.

Comment: $E_{2k}(z) = \sum_{4a+6b=2k} c_{a,b} E_4(z)^a E_6(z)^b$ for some $c_{a,b}\in \Bbb{Q}$ that you find by looking at the first few coefficients. This follows from that $\Delta(z)=\frac{E_4(z)^3-E_6(z)^2}{1728}$ is a modular form with only one simple zero at $i\infty$, so for $f$ of weight $m$ then $g(z)=\frac{f(z)-f(i\infty) E_4(z)^a E_6(z)^b}{\Delta(z)}$ is a modular form of weight $m-12$. When $m<12$ this implies that $g(z)=0$.